# echo $this->element('sql_dump'); without debug and in a mail

Tags: cakephp

In CAKEPHP the function `$this->element('sql_dump')` prints the executed sql querys on the screen.
`$this->element('sql_dump')` is only available with `debug mode = 2`

This works fine but I would like the following to work:

- Debug mode has to be 0
- I do not want to `echo` the sql dump on the screen but mail it to myself
- This has to happen with the click on a button (send bug report)

Is this possible, how?

Thanks for you help

Comment: With debug = 0 there is no logging AFAIK (for performance reasons). So this seems to be impossible to do in live environments without hacking the core.

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Elements/sql_dump.ctp  (the actual sql_dump element - for anyone interested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get debugging info when debug mode is 0 you have to manipulate the data source before executing your query.

In your controller:

```
$db = $this->MyModel->getDataSource();
$db->fullDebug = true;
$this->MyModel->find(...);
$log = $db->getLog();
$db->fullDebug = false;
// email yourself the log
```